# How to fill a fontawesome icon with a background on hover?

Tags: css, sass, background, hover, font-awesome

I'm trying to fill a fontawesome icon with a linear gradient, when hovered

```
<button class="vignet_like">
    <i class="far fa-heart heart_icon"></i>
</button>
```

With

```
.heart_icon:hover { linear-gradient (95deg, lightgreen 0%, lightblue 100%); }
```

I obviously got a [squared background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyqZp.jpg) ; I want the background only inside icon.

I tried different approachs with no succes, so before going to work on SVGs, i wanted to know if there is a solution using CSS

Comment: in this case you need to use different icon. On hover you need to load filed version of icon you are using

Comment: Thanks for your answer @StefanP. Yes we can use color propery on icons. Unfortunatly we can't use linear gradient with it